# Ruby Gems suddenly stopped working on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rbenv

After a couple of days of not doing pretty much anything on the ubuntu box, I decided to try out some ruby stuff. For this, I wanted to fire up `pry`. Unfortunately, I was presented with

> Sorry, you can't use Pry without Readline or a compatible library.
>   Please `gem install rb-readline` or recompile Ruby --with-readline.
>
> ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': libreadline.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory -
>   ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so
>   (LoadError)

Being quite new to linux in general, I figured I'd just do as it said, and install this `rb-readline`. The installation passes just fine, but doesnt seem to do anything at all. If I do `gem list p`, the package just doesn't appear.

So yeah, I just don't know what to do to get it working again, and the only thing I managed to find by searching was related to an installation without rbenv and had something to do with sudo etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Without understanding the problem and following the advice in option 2 of the message:

```
Sorry, you can't use Pry without Readline or a compatible library.
 Possible solutions:

 * Rebuild Ruby with Readline support using `--with-readline`
 * Use the rb-readline gem, which is a pure-Ruby port of Readline  <==== Option 2
 * Use the pry-coolline gem, a pure-ruby alternative to Readline
```

I added the gem into the Gemfile (as follows), bundled and pry was then available.

`group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rb-readline'
end`

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem too. I am using rbenv and reinstalling ruby via

`rbenv install -f 2.2.3`

did fixed it for me. Of course you'd put in your respective version. -f forces the installation even though you already have that specific version installed. use `rbenv global` to find out what version you have installed and set.

Answer (score 1):

I have some problem. But I don't want to add gem 'rb-readline'. So try it...

$ln  -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib

Answer (score 0):

Do a `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev`, seems like you're missing the readline shared library that pry is wanting. If it worked before, not sure why the library isn't there anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it seems to be installed, this is what I got "libreadline-dev is already the newest version." I also checked that directory, and the .so file actually exists in that directory...

Comment: Next thing I would do then would be to check that the version of ruby being used with rbenv is the same version that rubygems is trying to pick up. Show me the output of `env` and `gem env`, in `gem env` look to see what RUBY VERSION, INSTALLATION DIRECTORY, and RUBY EXECUTABLE entries give you. Chances are you could have installed two different versions of ruby and rubygems is getting confused.

Comment: I had just one - 2.1.1, listed everywhere I managed to look at. And there's no ruby installed at system-level at all - if I did sudo ruby --version, I get a command not found

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing `rbenv uninstall`, followed by `rbenv install` and re-installing all the gems, and got it back to working. Still no idea what caused it in the first place, but it works now.

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out. Check out my last comment under my answer for a possible explanation. Similar things have happened to me before using rvm... :(